# Convert YYYY.(MM/12) Using Custom Date Formats

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I'm parsing a table that contains dates in a few different formats. I've identified at least five potential date formats I need to handle. So my current setup (for the easy four formats) is basically something like the following:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string[] dateFormats = { "MM/yyyy", "M/yyyy", "yyyy/MM", "yyyy/M" };
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(someDateString, dateFormats, cultureInfo,
                            DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out someDate))
{
    throw new someException("Unable to parse date");
}
```

This works great. However, for the fifth format, I'm not sure what to do. The format is basically `YYYY.(MM/12)`. For example, if `2014.25` is provided, then it should be interpreted as `April 1, 2014`.

I've searched through the [standard/custom date format specifiers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I don't see any reference to adding custom date formats outside of the standard specifiers (of which, a year fraction doesn't seem to be an option).

Is there a built-in way to add this kind of format, or do I have to write my own parser? I'm trying to avoid splitting it into another parser just to keep fairly standardized. Thankfully, it doesn't look like I will ever have to handle `YYYY.MM`, so at least I should be able check for this date format by using `someDateString.Contains('.')`.

Comment: This almost feels like failing an intelligence test, but: how exactly does 2014.25 formatted as YYYY.(MM/12) map on April 1, 2014?

Comment: @Olaf: It's wherever `MM/12 = 0.25`. So `MM = 0.25*12 = 3 (in full months)` which occurs at exactly `4/1/2014 00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there's no custom date format that covers that problem (which I found quite interesting after a moment). So **yes**, you have to write your own parser.

For the fun of it I did it - I believe the correct approach would be to view 0.25 as a fraction of the year and then write a tiny script.

An exact calculation based on seconds (even checking if this is a leap year) would be something like

```
var someDateString = "2014.25";
if(someDateString.Contains(".")) {
    var parts = someDateString.Split('.');
    var year = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
    var secondsPerYear = DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? 31622400 : 31536000;
    var seconds = Double.Parse(parts[1])/100 * secondsPerYear;
    var newDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddSeconds(seconds);
}
```

This does indeed write the exact date (in this case April 2nd) into newDate. If you need the full month, you can of course use new DateTime(newDate.Year, newDate.Month, 1).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution for seconds precision. I decided to restrict my precision to months, which gives a slightly different approach (I'll post it as an answer). However I'll mark your response as the answer, in case anyone needs to handle the general case.

Comment: @grovesNL - thanks. I had no doubt you could write that code yourself - I just found thinking about it interesting, because I also started with a lower precision.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a parser to do this.

Because I don't need to use seconds precision, I decided to handle month precision through a slightly different approach than Olaf's answer:

```
int[] dateSplit = someDateString.Split('.').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
int month = Convert.ToInt32(dateSplit[1] * 0.12);
if (!(month < 12))
    throw new someException;
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(dateSplit[0], month + 1, 1);
```

...which gives me the expected output of April 1st. There are obviously some limitations to this approach, especially if the database format also allows `YYYY.MM`.